# Program is installed in two locations. How do I fix this

Tags: package-management

I installed netbeans using terminal apt install and also installed netbeans by downloading the program and installing the tar.gz file (i think).  Now I have two versions of the same program running on my system. How do I fix this? When checking dpkg --list it listed 1 installation of netbeans.  I uninstalled this. But now how can I uninstal the other installation. It's not listed.

Comment: uninstall one of them

Comment: @ravery edited.

Answer (score 2):

You installed netbeans from the repositories by using the `sudo apt install` command. Then later you uninstalled it, after `dpkg` showed this one as being installed.

You also installed netbeans from a .tar.gz file, which is source code. You probably did this...

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To uninstall this version, go back to the source code folder and type...

```
sudo make uninstall
```